# Configuring spring security using oAuth and form based authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a server application with two components: 
a) A set of REST API that are secured using oAuth ( Spring security oAuth)
b) A dashboard for management with role based UI

For business reasons, these two components need to be co-hosted i.e deployed as a single war.
Till now we only had oAuth for our REST API's and all was well.
The problem started when we tried to use form based authentication for the dashboard. Now, when we access REST API's without an oAuth token, it just redirects to the login page instead of giving a 401 unauthorized error.
Our configuration is like this:
Form based authentication(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter):

```
 http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/css/**","/img/**","/login/**","/oauth/**).permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/delegate/success", true)
            .failureUrl("/login/fail")
                .permitAll()
           .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")                                  
            .permitAll();
```

oAuth:

Resource provider configuration:

```
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/abc").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')and hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/xyz").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

We would basically like to configure different API to be secured differently. REST API consumed by client applications have to be secured by oAuth and Spring MVC API rendering dashboard pages with form based authentication.
Is this even possible?

EDIT:
Add ordering and able to get 401 unauthorized message on accessing oauth protected REST APIs. Form login doesnt work though. I am able to access all dashboard pages without login.
More code snippets:

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceProviderConfiguration extends   ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    .....
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/abc").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')and  hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                    .antMatchers("/xyz").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and  hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").
.and()
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/abc","/xyz","/others");

       }

    }
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationProviderConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    ClientDetailsService webClientDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    .......
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
    ......
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(5)
    public class UserAuthenticationConfiguration extends     WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()                              
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/img/**","/login/**",
             "/oauth/**).permitAll()
                     .anyRequest().authenticated()
                 .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
              .defaultSuccessUrl("/delegate/success", true)
                .failureUrl("/login/fail")
                    .permitAll()
               .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")                                  
                .permitAll();

    }
    }
```

Spring security logs:

```
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant    [pattern='/oauth/token']
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/oauth/token'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/oauth/token_key'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/oauth/check_token'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/abc/**']
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/abc/**'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/xyz/**']
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/xyz/**'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@7f8059. A new one will be created.
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@cebda04
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/logout'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET '/def'' doesn't match 'POST /login/new
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 794828541EF505314237BBC81C2ACAF4; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/css/**'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/oauth/**'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/img/**'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/def'; against '/login/**'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - '/def' reached end of additional     filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'webservice' processing GET request for ['/handler/def']
```

Final Configuration that worked:
1. Adding @Order to the web security configurer, after the resource provider configuration which defaults to 3.

2. Ensuring that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has .anyRequest().authenticated() config

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableResourceServer
   public class ResourceProviderConfiguration extends   ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
   .....
   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
               .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/abc").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')and   hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                   .antMatchers("/xyz").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')   and  hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").
                   .and()
                   .requestMatchers()
                   .antMatchers("/abc","/xyz","/others");

      }

   }
   @Configuration
   @EnableAuthorizationServer
   public class AuthorizationProviderConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private TokenStore tokenStore;

   @Autowired
   private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

   @Autowired
   ClientDetailsService webClientDetailsService;


   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
   private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

   .......
   @Bean
   public TokenStore tokenStore() {
       return new InMemoryTokenStore();
   }
   ......
   }

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @Order(5)
   public class UserAuthenticationConfiguration extends     WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
           .csrf().disable()
           .authorizeRequests()                              
           .antMatchers("/css/**","/img/**","/login/**",
            "/oauth/**).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
               .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
             .defaultSuccessUrl("/delegate/success", true)
               .failureUrl("/login/fail")
                   .permitAll()
              .and()
           .logout()
               .logoutUrl("/logout")
               .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")                                  
               .permitAll();

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: What `@Order` do you use on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (it needs to come *after* the `ResourceServerConfiguration` which defaults to 3)?

Comment: We added an ordering of 1 for ResourceServerConfiguration and 2 for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. It still shows the same behaviour. Unauthorized REST API access redirects to the login page

Comment: How did you change the order of the `ResourceServerConfiguration`? (I wouldn't have done that.)

Comment: Right . Thats approach didnt work. I have now changed ResourceServerConfiguration to @Order(3) and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to @Order(4). I do get the 401 unauthorized error for REST API's but the web configuration doesnt work! I am able to access any link in the dashboard without authentication. We also use the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter and GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration. Any inherent order I am missing here? I couldnt find any documentation regarding this. Do share if you have a link. Thanks!

Comment: I can't really tell what you did without seeing more code. Why do you even have a `ResourceServerConfiguration` (usualy you import it using `@EnableResourceServer`)?

Comment: For what its worth, added more code snippets

Comment: You don't have a request matcher on your `ResourceServerConfigurer` so it defaults to `anyRequest()` and there is no access rule for any resource other than /abc and /xyz so everything else is `permitAll()`. Add a request matcher and I think it might work.

Comment: The `@Order` on your oauth2 configurers isn't doing what you think though - they are for ordering configurers of the same type (you can simply remove those).

Comment: @Dave, I removed the oAuth config ordering. Added  request matchers in the resource provider config. But thats not doing the trick. The oAuth config is actually working fine. I am able to get a token, access API with the token and I get a 401 on unauthorized access. But form login just doesnt work. I would expect API not protected by oAuth would default to form based authentication, but that is not happening. Updated code

Comment: Switch on DEBUG logging for org.springframework.security and you will see the request matchers being applied to your request. That should give you a clue.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for pointing me to the spring security debug logs. It did turn up something interesting. I have edited with the logs

Comment: I didn't see any logs yet.

Comment: @Dave, sorry just added. Looks like the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is invoked, but not interpreted as a redirect to /login/new

Comment: I can see it checking your `permitAll()` matchers (why is `/oauth/**` on that list BTW - looks dangerous to me?), but there's no sign of the `anyRequest().authenticated()`. Maybe you need to add a request matcher to the `HttpSecurity` as well (i.e. `http.requestMatchers().anyRequest()`)?

Comment: @Dave, thanks a ton. You nailed it. I initially had anyRequest().authenticated() in web security but it got overridden at some point. You might want to answer the question so I can acept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see it checking your `permitAll()` matchers in the logs, but there's no sign of the `anyRequest().authenticated()`. You need to add a request matcher to the `HttpSecurity` as well (i.e. `http.requestMatchers().anyRequest()`).